# Lenovo Ideapad S145-15API Precision Touchpad Driver

Tags: windows-10, drivers, touchpad, lenovo-laptop, synaptics-touchpad

I have an Ideapad S145-15API and my precision touchpad worked perfectly fine before I clean installed Windows. And now I've tried uninstalling the driver and updating it, it showed "The best drivers for your device are already installed." I tried editing the registry for the two finger right click too, but nothing has worked for me. I'm pretty sure this is a driver issue, i just can't find the right driver (I've checked my product support page on Lenovo too.)

(Synaptics Touchpad and Windows 10 Version 2004, OS Build: 19041.329)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Run Lenovo System Update to ensure all drivers have been installed. You need to do this if your fresh install was not from the Lenovo USB Recovery Key

Comment: @John Yeah I ran it and it showed that there are no new updates available for my system.

Answer (score -1):

https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/ideapad-s-series-netbooks/s145-15api/downloads/DS540472

https://download.lenovo.com/consumer/mobiles/6yst04af40cm90.exe

Try this link, it worked for me.